# EDIFACT format to send EDI message status

Tags: edi, edifact

Is there any format to send an acknowledgement to the sender , if there is any missing information or invalid data.

Our AS2 provider has the MDN facility. so from there we can know whether the message is received or not.

But what if there is an error while parsing the message because of some invalid data. In this case how we can send an acknowledgement back to the sender.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Look at the CONTRL message [CONTRL](https://www.stylusstudio.com/edifact/40100/CONTRL.htm)

Answer (score 1):

In the Netherlands the APERAK message is widely used exactly for that purpose: https://www.gs1.org/standards/edi-xml-gs1-eancom/eancom-aperak-s3/syntax-3

Comment: Please note: GS1 has theeir own EDI standard called EANCOM
You have some differences, use of qualifiers and a more restricted layout

Comment: You can use the dcumentation at stylus studio: 
https://www.stylusstudio.com/edifact/D96A/APERAK.htm, or Truugo: https://www.truugo.com/edifact/d96a/aperak/